# Menu Wordpress - Toggle não abre quando aperta

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, toggle

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Wordpress, e tenho problemas com meu menu.
Quando testo o site em resoluções menores, a caixinha do toggle não abre ele.
Como me embaralho bastante com a questão do HTML junto do PHP, creio que falta algo para fazer com que apertando a caixinha do toggle o menu abra pra baixo normalmente.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="dbn-header-flex">


      <div class="dbn-header-menu">

        <?php 

          wp_nav_menu( array(
                  'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                  'depth'           => 3,
                  'container'       => 'div',
                  'container_class' => 'dbn-header-menu hidden-sm hidden-xs',
                  'container_id'    => '',
                  'menu_class'      => 'dbn-menu',
                  'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                  'walker'          => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker(), // Apply bootstrap menu mode
                ) ); 
              ?>

      </div>



      <div class="dbn-header-search">

         <?php
          // Busca
          include('searchform.php'); ?>
      </div>

      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div> <!-- /.dbn-header-flex -->

  </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
  </div><!-- /. row -->
```

Comment: Peter. Possivelmente as classes `hidden-sm hidden-xs` estão ocultando seu `menu` nas resoluções **≥768px a <991px** e **<768px**, respectivamente. Remova-as e faça o teste para ver se resolve.

Comment: Então, de qualquer forma, mesmo tirando essas classes, o menu aparece, mas não fica dentro da caixinha toggle.

O certo seria clicar nela e abrir neh? Conforme o bootstrap, mas não ta rolando.

PHP com Wordpress e bootstrap, até me acostumar com isso, sempre me enrolo.

Comment: Seu `data-target` deve apontar para o **id** do menu. Por exemplo: `data-target="#idMenu` , caso seu menu tenha `<div id="idMenu" (...)>`. E neste caso para setar o seu id você deve referenciá-lo aqui: `'container_id'    => 'idMenu'`